# What is the difference between aneignen and erwerben?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, german-to-english

I have been struggling with the notion of "aneignen" in relation with "erwerben". Both seem to seem to translate to the English word "acquire", although seem to be highly context-specific. I was wondering if there was a clean translation between English and German between the two words. For example, when you learn a language, one would say

"Ich will mir diese Sprache aneignen."

Translated into English, you could say acquire, but then I ask, doesn't "erwerben" mean acquire? Other possible translations of aneignen includes "appropriate", but nobody would say that in everyday English.

Could somebody help clarify the difference here and if "aneignen" has a clear English translation, or at least provide some examples where one word would work and the other would not? Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 4):

You can use the verb **aneignen** (similar phrase: *zu eigen machen*) when talking about something you *grasped*:

> Dort **habe** ich mir alles über Töpferei **angeeignet/zu eigen gemacht**.

*There I **grasped** all about pottery.*

> Sie **eignete** sich die deutsche Sprache schnell **an**.

*She **grasped** the German language quickly.*

When not talking about learning, *aneignen* means *to take away*.

> Er ist auf dem Fahrad geflohen, das er sich zuvor **angeeignet hatte**.

*He flew on the bike he had taken away before.*

Police will report this instead of "gestohlen" because "stehlen" is an offense, while "aneignen" takes into account the bike could possibly belong to the person who took it away from somebody else.

---

**Erwerben** simply means **to acquire**.

> Dieses Bild **habe** ich vor Jahren **erworben**.

*I **acquired** this picture years ago.*

When talking about something you learned, it's the knowledge you acquired.

> Meine Töpferkenntnisse **habe** ich über Jahre **erworben**.

*I **acquired** my knowledge about making pottery over years.*

Comment: One of the key differences is that *erwerben* can also mean *to purchase*, that is, acquiring something in exchange for something else. *Aneignen* doesn't have this connotation.

Comment: @nwellnhof but aneignen has a connotation of active work for it. And it would be very strange if it was used for something like taking over someone else's property by theft or invasion / squatting. It would sound ironical in that sense, and probably quoted. You wouldn't use aneignen much for an object anyway, rather an intangible, like a skill. And you can use erwerben too but you would have to spell out the skill "Er erwarb die Fähigkeit schöne Gedichte zu verfassen."

Comment: @GuntherSchadow There's nothing strange about using *aneignen* to describe theft or in connection with objects. Just Google for *"Täter eignete sich"*.

Comment: @nwellnhof true, it is used, but it might be used in this slightly ironic form. To my ears it sounds as having a sprinkle of irony on it.

Answer (score 3):

For the specific case of "acquiring" a language, both may be possible. I think *erwerben* would be much more usual for acquiring a language, and other similar kinds of competencies. *Spracherwerb*, "language acquisition", is a standard fixed phrase.

More generally, the difference is something like between *erwerben* as "come to have" and *aneignen* "take possession of, appropriate". (I don't think appropriate in this sense is that unusual a word in English). *aneignen* has a stronger sense of taking something that exists, which belongs to someone and making it your own (the root is "eigen", compare the verb *enteignen*, "expropriate").

Labels in a museum or art collection will often tell visitors when an artwork  was *erworben*, but the museum would probably not want visitors to think that the piece was *angeeignet*. The museum came to have a particular piece, perhaps by purchase or bequest, but the piece should not have been "seized".

A good strategy for distinguishing between seemingly similar verbs is to look at the back-translations: http://www.dict.cc/?s=spracherwerb